# How to do Group by in hibernate when multiple Table are present?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring-boot

I have SQL query with multiple tables and applied GROUP BY clause too. How to write corresponding hibernate query for that? and I wish to get "EcomMaincat" (ecom_maincat) entity list as a query result, is it possible? Please help!

```
SELECT   c.company_id, c.cat_id, MAX (c.Name) Name
    FROM   ecom_menu_subcat sc,
           ecom_subcat_brand sb,
           ecom_maincat c,
           ecom_menu_subcat menusub
   WHERE       sc.company_id = sb.company_id
           AND sc.cat_id = sb.cat_id
           AND sc.sub_cat_id = sb.sub_cat_Id
           AND sb.company_id = menusub.company_id
           AND sb.cat_id = menusub.cat_id
           AND sb.sub_cat_id = menusub.sub_cat_id
           AND sc.company_id = c.company_id
           AND sc.cat_id = c.cat_id
           AND sb.company_id = :companyId
           AND sb.Brand_id = :brandId
           AND menusub.Menu_id = NVL (:menuId, menusub.Menu_id)
GROUP BY   c.company_id, c.cat_id
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use session.createSQLQuery(String sql) method !!

Comment: ya.. that's fine.. but how to apply Hibernate Criteria API  using EntityManager to this query?

Comment: EntityManager is in JPA and in hibernate we use Session !!! EntityManager invokes hibernate session under the hood , so you can try "Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);" to get session and then get criteria from it .

Answer (score 0):

you can use @ManytoOne or @OnetoMany Annotations in hibernate
[click here](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/best-practices-many-one-one-many-associations-mappings/)